# TypeScript Controller not handling HTTP promises

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-promise

I have been learning Angular and everything's been going smoothly. I have decided to try and incorporate TypeScript into this and wrote a small test controller in an already existing Angular/WebApi project I have been working on.

The controller "works" and initializes just fine, however, my `$scope` properties are not being updated when set to an HTTP promise. I have attached a "working" example of my issue using the TypeScript generated JS file. When debugging, I can see the `then` get triggered on the promise and the data I expected does `return`, but the page displays `{}`

Here is my actual TypeScript file.

```
/// <reference path="../../tds/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
module RecordEditor {
    export interface Scope extends ng.IScope{
        tableId: any;
    }

    export class Controller {
        $scope: Scope;
        api : any;
        constructor($scope: Scope, myApi: any) {
            this.api = myApi;
            this.$scope = $scope;
            this.$scope.tableId = this.api.getTestResponse();
        }
    }
}

var app = angular.module("myApp");
app.controller("RecordEditor.Controller", ['$scope', 'myApi', RecordEditor.Controller]);
```

That controller is the only thing I have actually written in TypeScript. All the other controllers are in JavaScript and the same `api` I built returns responses just fine with those.

Below is the actual runnable snippet code with the JavaScript version of my Controller.

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

}());

(function() {
  var myApi = function($http) {

    var getTestResponse = function() {
      // Hope it is okay to use SE API to test this question. Sorry if not.
      return $http.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites")
        .then(function(response) {
          return "Hello!";
        });
    };

    return {
      getTestResponse: getTestResponse,
    };

  };

  var module = angular.module("myApp");
  module.service("myApi", ['$http', myApi]);
}());

var RecordEditor;
(function(RecordEditor) {
  var Controller = (function() {
    function Controller($scope, myApi) {
      var _this = this;
      this.api = myApi;
      this.$scope = $scope;
      this.$scope.response = this.api.getTestResponse();

      this.$scope.ctorTest = 42;
    }
    return Controller;
  })();
  RecordEditor.Controller = Controller;
})(RecordEditor || (RecordEditor = {}));

var app = angular.module("myApp");
app.controller("RecordEditor.Controller", ['$scope', 'myApi', RecordEditor.Controller]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="RecordEditor.Controller">
  <div >
    Scope property set in constructor: {{ctorTest}}
  </div>
  
  <div >
    Scope response value: {{response}}
  </div>

  <div >
    Scope response should have been "Hello!"
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone actually tell me what I am doing wrong? Everything looks fine to me.

Comment: Seems like the stackexchange call isnt working. Check this JSFiddle for the one that is working. http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7382/

Comment: @KrishnaTejaVeeramachaneni That's the odd thing though. No errors report in the console when using the URL and I get no errors when calling my own service locally, but the result is exactly the same (`{}` on page instead of `Hello!`). And that's calling a method on the `api` that the other controllers can call just fine. I see your example has it working though. I am very lost right now.

Comment: Not sure why you were not seeing error in console but I was able to see 404 errors in chrome console.

Comment: Whomever had the answer for calling `getTestResponse().then(...) ` please undelete your answer. It was correct.

Comment: @KrishnaTejaVeeramachaneni I am not getting 404s calling that URL.

Comment: It was me but I wanted to create a better jsFiddle with a better explaination. Please check my answer now.

Comment: Sorry @KrishnaTejaVeeramachaneni, it was the other answer someone posted. They deleted (not sure why) right as I was about to mark it. I have added a placeholder answer to show what the actual issue was. You are correct on using `success` and I normally do, but I removed it for testing to see if that was causing issues. Thanks though!

Comment: Undeleted - sorry for the confusion; I was uncertain about the fix being 100% correct and was hoping someone with more Angular expertise could chime in with more certainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var getTestResponse = function() {
  return $http.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites")
    .then(function(response) {
      return "Hello!"; // <-- does not do what you think it does
    });
};

/** elsewhere **/
this.$scope.response = this.api.getTestResponse();
```

The inner `return` statement here does *not* return a value from `getTestResponse`. Instead, it returns a value *from the Promise* which is basically discarded. `getTestResponse` returns immediately with a Promise object that is of no particular use for binding to the scope.

Fixed version of the JS:

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

}());

(function() {
  var myApi = function($http) {

    var getTestResponse = function() {
      // Hope it is okay to use SE API to test this question. Sorry if not.
      return $http.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites")
        .then(function(response) {
          return "Hello!";
        });
    };

    return {
      getTestResponse: getTestResponse,
    };

  };

  var module = angular.module("myApp");
  module.service("myApi", ['$http', myApi]);
}());

var RecordEditor;
(function(RecordEditor) {
  var Controller = (function() {
    function Controller($scope, myApi) {
      var _this = this;
      this.api = myApi;
      this.$scope = $scope;
      /** FIXED **/
      this.api.getTestResponse().then(function(v) { _this.$scope.response = v; });

      this.$scope.ctorTest = 42;
    }
    return Controller;
  })();
  RecordEditor.Controller = Controller;
})(RecordEditor || (RecordEditor = {}));

var app = angular.module("myApp");
app.controller("RecordEditor.Controller", ['$scope', 'myApi', RecordEditor.Controller]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="RecordEditor.Controller">
  <div >
    Scope property set in constructor: {{ctorTest}}
  </div>
  
  <div >
    Scope response value: {{response}}
  </div>

  <div >
    Scope response should have been "Hello!"
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the one spot it was wrong in my base as a template for setting up the TypeScript class. Everywhere else I was using `then`. D'OH! The TypeScript fix was this `this.api.getTestResponse().then((v: any): void => this.$scope.tableId = v);`

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's the issue. You are trying to set your response to the actual callback function.
Instead, you have to set the response property inside callback using the response you got from the http call.

Here is the api function

```
 var getTestResponse = function() {         
      return $http.get("http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http%3A//vimeo.com/76979871");            
    };
```

Here is your controller code where you have to set your response property to bind to UI.

```
 _this.api.getTestResponse().success(function(resp) { 
      _this.$scope.response = resp.height; //I just used height property from response as example
  });
```

Here is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7386/

Make sure you first get your stackexachange call working. I used vimeo call as example.
Let me know if you have any questions.

So, in your TypeScript code, you have to change

```
this.$scope.tableId = this.api.getTestResponse();
```

to

```
this.api.getTestResponse().then((resp) =>
{
    this.$scope.tableId = resp;
});
```

And make your API just return a promise.